# How to avoid component disappearing when minimizing frame Java

Tags: java

The following code draws a circle in a specific position but I noticed when I maximize or minimize the frame, the circle disappears in case of the frame minimizing and it doesn't move when I maximize the frame.

SimpleFrame Class

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class SimpleFrame extends JFrame{

    public SimpleFrame(){
        setTitle("Test");
        setSize(WIDTH,HEIGHT);

        Container con = this.getContentPane();
        draw = new MyPanel();
        con.add(draw);
    }

    public static final int WIDTH = 300;
    public static final int HEIGHT = 200;

    private MyPanel draw;
}
```

MyPanel Class:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.geom.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class MyPanel extends JPanel{
    public MyPanel(){
        setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    }

    //override the default paintComponent method in JComponent
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g; //Drawing shapes using the Java2D library requires a Graphics2D object
        g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(5));
        g2.setPaint(new Color(128,0,0));
        Shape[] shapeList = new Shape[3];
        //shapeList[0] = new Rectangle2D.Double(20.0,20.0,40.0,70.0);
        shapeList[1] = new Ellipse2D.Double(70.0,10.0,60.0,60.0);
        g2.draw(shapeList[1]);
    }
}
```

SimpleFrameTest class:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class SimpleFrameTest {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        JFrame frm = new SimpleFrame();
        frm.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frm.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

How can I solve that issue?

Comment: With minimizing you mean exiting fullscreen mode back to normal or rather really minimizing so that the window disappears in the status bar?

Comment: @Raven I mean resizing the frame not exiting fullscreen

Comment: Have you tried to use another layout manager?

Comment: @Raven No. Can you tell me please which layout is better

Comment: I can't tell you which one exactly you have to use... But you should give BoxLayout, FlowLayout or GridBagLayout a try ;)

Comment: I really can't reproduce your problem, I tested your code under Windows 7 using Oracle JDK 8 and Linux OpenJDK 7, OpenJDK 8 and Oracle JDK 8 and it always runs without any problems...